# PySide6 За что отвечает parent в QGraphicsDropShadowEffect

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyside6, findchildren

Допустим есть `QFrame`, от которого должна падать тень:

```
frame = QFrame(parent, Geometry=QRect(10, 10, 50, 50))
frame.setGraphicsEffect(QGraphicsDropShadowEffect(centralWidget, blurRadius=15, offset=QPoint(0, 0), color=QColor(0, 0, 0, 200)))
```

Вместо `centralWidget` можно написать что угодно - хоть `frame`, хоть `QLabel` на фрейме, если бы он там был, в общем любой элемент интерфейса, но без него тени нет.

За что все-таки отвечает этот параметр и что туда правильно писать?

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: За автоматическое удаление этого объекта по цепочке удаления (родители удаляют своих детей, те своих детей и так далее) https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/objecttrees.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В документации
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setGraphicsEffect
указано, что один и тот же `QGraphicsEffect` не может использоваться другими виджетами:

Если эффект установлен на другом виджете, `setGraphicsEffect()`
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setGraphicsEffect
удалит эффект из виджета и установит его на этот виджет.

Таким образом, вам нужно будет создать `QGraphicsEffect` для каждого виджета,
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicseffect.html
но если вы не хотите писать много кода и хотите применять эффекты с похожими характеристиками,
вы можете перебирать виджеты и для этого использовать **`findChildren(...)`** .
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#findChildren

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Container(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, window, parent=None):
        super(Container, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)
        
        centralWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)

        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(
            '<h1>Hello World</h1>', alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setFixedSize(140, 30)    
        self.label.setStyleSheet("background-color: transparent;")  
        self.button1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Button 1')
        self.button1.setFixedSize(100, 100)
        self.button2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Button 2')
        self.button2.setFixedSize(100, 100)
        
        glay = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(window)       
        glay.addWidget(self.label, 0, 0, 1, 2, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        glay.addWidget(self.button1, 1, 0, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        glay.addWidget(self.button2, 1, 1, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        
        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(centralWidget)
        lay.addWidget(window)
        lay.setContentsMargins(10, 10, 10, 10)

# !!!                        vvvvvvvvvvvv     
        for children in self.findChildren(QtWidgets.QWidget):
            shadow = QtWidgets.QGraphicsDropShadowEffect(
                blurRadius=5, 
                color=QtGui.QColor(99, 255, 255),
                xOffset=3, 
                yOffset=3
            )
            children.setGraphicsEffect(shadow)
# !!!

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.oldPos = event.globalPos()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        delta = QtCore.QPoint (event.globalPos() - self.oldPos)
        self.move(self.x() + delta.x(), self.y() + delta.y())
        self.oldPos = event.globalPos()
 

class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('Icon')
        self.setWindowFlag(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)
        
    def paintEvent(self, ev):
        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing)        
        painter.setBrush(QtGui.QColor(195, 195, 255))
        painter.setPen(QtCore.Qt.NoPen)
        painter.drawRoundedRect(self.rect(), 10.0, 10.0)
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle('fusion')
    w = Window()
    container = Container(w)
    container.resize(640, 480)
    container.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]